# How do I connect to ssh using Airflows SSHOperator?

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to connect to an ec2 instance with airflow using the SSHOperator but my dag fails with the following error message:

```
[2020-05-24 06:17:04,191] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 146, in execute
[2020-05-24 06:17:04,191] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e)))
[2020-05-24 06:17:04,191] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exec_command'
```

Here's my source code:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
...

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=DAG)

t2 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='my_ec2_connection',
    task_id='ssh_operator',
    command='ls',
    dag=DAG)

t1 >> t2
```

I've setup the pem file using ssh connection in the UI and also did the ssh-add of the pem key.

Comment: It looks like the `SSHHook` cannot create an SSH client with the provided configuration and its `get_conn()` returns `None` to the `SSHOperator`. I would try to debug the SSHHook to find out why it returns `None` https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.html